# getDeclaredMethods() behaving differently in Java 7 vs. Java 8

Tags: java, java-8

Consider the following little example:

```
package prv.rli.codetest;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class BreakingInterfaces  {
    interface Base {
        BaseFoo foo();
        interface BaseFoo {           
        }
    }

    interface Derived extends Base {
        DerivedFoo foo();
        interface DerivedFoo extends BaseFoo {

        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {       
        dumpDeclaredMethods(Derived.class);
    }

    private static void dumpDeclaredMethods(Class<?> class1) {
        System.out.println("---" + class1.getSimpleName() + "---");
        Method[] methods = class1.getDeclaredMethods();
        for (Method method : methods) {
            System.out.println(method);
        }
        System.out.println("----------");
    }
}
```

If you compile the above example with jdk1.7.0.55 the output is:

```
 ---Derived---
public abstract BreakingInterfaces$Derived$DerivedFoo BreakingInterfaces$Derived.foo()
----------
```

But when using jdk1.8.0.25 the output is:

```
---Derived---
public abstract prv.rli.codetest.BreakingInterfaces$Derived$DerivedFoo prv.rli.codetest.BreakingInterfaces$Derived.foo()
public default prv.rli.codetest.BreakingInterfaces$Base$BaseFoo prv.rli.codetest.BreakingInterfaces$Derived.foo()
----------
```

Does anybody know, whether this is a bug in jdk1.8.0.25 or why the public default Method resurfaces here?

Comment: 'm guessing here, but it might be something to do with java8 default implementation of methods in interface.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`getDeclaredMethods()` behaves correctly here as it tells you exactly what it has found in the class. If you feed in an `interface` compiled with Java 7 target (or an older compiler) you will see no difference to the output of the Java 7 implementation of `getDeclaredMethods()`.

It’s the *compiler* which behaves differently. When compiling such a sub-`interface` in Java 8, a bridge method will be generated which will not be generated for a Java 7 target as it is not even possible for the Java 7 target.

The reason why bridge methods are generated for interfaces now is that you usually have more implementation classes than interfaces, therefore having a `default` bridge method in the interface saves you from adding that bridge method to every implementation. Further, it makes lambda class generation much easier if there is only one `abstract` method and no bridge method to implement.

When an `interface` hierarchy requires bridge methods but provides no `default`s, the compiler has to generate code using [`LambdaMetafactory.altMetafactory`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/LambdaMetafactory.html#altMetafactory-java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles.Lookup-java.lang.String-java.lang.invoke.MethodType-java.lang.Object...-) rather than [`LambdaMetafactory.metafactory`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/LambdaMetafactory.html#metafactory-java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles.Lookup-java.lang.String-java.lang.invoke.MethodType-java.lang.invoke.MethodType-java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle-java.lang.invoke.MethodType-) specifying every bridge method that is required.

Answer (score 0):

Pardon the furstration, but it must be in a parallel universe where the Javadoc wording adequately explains this behavior: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredMethods--. An array of "all the declared methods" turns out to be an array of "all declared methods by the user *and by some under-the-hood implementation detail explained on StackOverflow*". Even worse, I'm seeing something weird about annotations: I'm overriding a generic method while applying an annotation, and both `abstract`&`default` methods returned by `getDeclaredMethods()` have the annotation, but only the `abstract` one has the correct non-generic parameters. So it seems to me this implementation detail partly defeats the purpose of searching for a method by annotation.