# AbstractMethodException with LambdaMetafactory

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

As a follow-up question strongly related to [Holgers' solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27420303/1431016), why does uncommenting the override break the working code below?

```
public static interface StringFunction<N extends Number> extends Function<String, N> {

  // @Override
  // N apply(String t);

}
```

This works only, if the comments above are not removed:

```
public static <N extends Number> StringFunction<N> create(Class<N> type) throws Throwable {
  MethodType methodType = MethodType.methodType(type, String.class);
  MethodHandles.Lookup lookup = MethodHandles.lookup();
  MethodHandle handle = lookup.findConstructor(type, 
    MethodType.methodType(void.class, String.class));
  StringFunction<N> f = (StringFunction<N>) LambdaMetafactory.metafactory(lookup, "apply", 
        MethodType.methodType(StringFunction.class), 
        methodType.generic(), handle, methodType).getTarget().invokeExact();
  return f;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
  System.out.println(create(Byte.class).apply("1"));
  System.out.println(create(Short.class).apply("2"));
  System.out.println(create(Integer.class).apply("3"));
  System.out.println(create(Long.class).apply("4"));
}
```

The runtime complains about:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError:
Method LambdaFun$$Lambda$1.apply(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Number; is abstract
  at LambdaFun$$Lambda$1/856419764.apply(Unknown Source)
  at LambdaFun.main(LambdaFun.java:28)
```

Comment: You do realize that `LambdaMetafactory` is primarily only for compiler writers, not ordinary java code, right?  By all means have fun trying it out, but it's a tool for experts, and using it requires deep understanding of how VM linkage works.  So you shouldn't be surprised that using it requires a high degree of precision and the resulting error messages for misuse are not trivially interpreted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using generic `interface`s with the metafactory, you need to understand how Generics work on the bytecode level.

When declaring an `interface` method like

```
public static interface StringFunction<N extends Number> extends Function<String, N> {
    @Override
    N apply(String t);
  }
```

the raw type `StringFunction` will have a method with the signature of `Number apply(String)` that you have to implement. It further contains a compiler generated bridge method overriding the the inherited method `Object apply(Object)` which will delegate to the `abstract` method (which is a good thing as otherwise, e.g. when the `interface` was compiled under Java 7 or earlier, we would have to declare all required bridge methods explicitly using [`altMetafactory`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/LambdaMetafactory.html#altMetafactory-java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles.Lookup-java.lang.String-java.lang.invoke.MethodType-java.lang.Object...-), compare [«this answer»](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27013899/2711488)).

So you have to change your factory method to:

```
public static <N extends Number> StringFunction<N> create(Class<N> type) throws Throwable {
    MethodType methodType = MethodType.methodType(type, String.class);
    MethodHandles.Lookup lookup = MethodHandles.lookup();
    MethodHandle handle = lookup.findConstructor(type, 
      MethodType.methodType(void.class, String.class));
    StringFunction<N> f = (StringFunction<N>) LambdaMetafactory.metafactory(lookup, "apply", 
      MethodType.methodType(StringFunction.class), 
      methodType.changeReturnType(Number.class), handle, methodType).getTarget().invokeExact();
    return f;
}
```

to make it work. Note that we now keep the `String` argument type that is fixed now and only change the return type to its lower bound using `methodType.changeReturnType(Number.class)`.

---

Further, note how this code may hide errors regarding Generics. You were using `Integer.class` at places supposed to be replaced by the parameter `type` but it doesn’t break immediately as your example code never tries to assign the value returned by such a function, e.g. `StringFunction<Short>` to a variable of that type, so you don’t notice that a `StringFunction<Short>` returns an `Integer`. I have fixed that in my example code, so that, e.g. `StringFunction<Short>` really return a `Short`.

Comment: Will edit the copy&paste error in my question as well. Thanks again for the detailed answer(s).